# Floor plan analysis

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, image-recognition, image-segmentation, ocr

Given an image of a floor plan, is there a known algorithm I can use to understand measurements of all apartments present ? (for example, that means in the attached picture understanding there are 4 apartments, and reading the measurements specified for each one?

I guess reading numbers (symbols) from an image should not be an issue, but the challenge is recognising the walls and understanding what apartment we're looking at out of the 4.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Converting a cad scanned image to a cad file, you can start with:
https://github.com/adityaintwala/Image2CAD

Now, you will need to go over a large amount of Cad drawings that are classified according to your needs.

A similar approach can be seen here:
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-01313-3

Comment: thanks. didn't really work unfortunately. I ran the image2Cad but it didn't manage to get correct results. You have an example of an image that worked well for you ?